# Listen to UIDocumentInteractionController and Whatsapp

Tags: ios, whatsapp, uidocumentinteraction

I am sharing a video to whatsapp using the typical UIDocumentInteractionController, I would like to:

1. Detect if the user actually opened another app with the
   documentController.
2. Detect if the user actually successfully shared
   the file in whatsapp.

Can't seem to get any detailed data from doccontroller or whatsapp.

Anyone knows how to do that?
Thx

Comment: For #1 see the `- documentInteractionController:didEndSendingToApplication:` delegate method.

Comment: For #2, it's not up to you to know what the user does when they leave your app. Kind of a privacy thing

Comment: For #, my bad, I did have the delegate implemented, but somehow after a Whatsapp update the documentInteractionController show 2 options "Whatsapp" which presents a vc modally without even putting the app in background. The other option is "open in Whatsapp" which make the app crash. I'll investigate.
For #2 it make sense, but still, when you share something over facebook from another app, the console returns a feedback.